# Recurrence relationship turned into a general formula

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

In wanting to see generating functions used in detail, I'd like to see how $$a(n)=\frac{4a(n-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{2+a(n-1)}$$ could be solved to have $a(n)$ in terms of only $n$. $a(1) $is immaterial but could be allowed to equal $1$.

Perhaps one could break this down to making a series expansion, noting 4*x^(1/3)/(2+x)=2*x^(1/3)-4*x^(4/3)+x^(7/3)/2...

Comment: That $\frac13$ seems to prevent any generating function from applying.

Comment: Is there a reason you’d expect generating functions to help here? This doesn’t, at first glance, seem like a good candidate.

Comment: All I ever see for applying generating functions for recurrence relationships are for very simple linear combinations. I'd think someone with a much stronger math ability than myself could show how we could apply to a slightly more difficult problem.

Comment: Tyty, I don't know anything about solving recurrence relations but judging by the comments it seems that this problem is not "slightly more difficult" but rather very much more difficult. If that is your wish, you should make a simpler example (e.g. if you don't want to see linear combinations, what about a quadratic recurrence?)